Ledger stax & solana cli [Error: no device found]
I am using Ledger Nano X and everything works fine with the CLI tool. However, I have purchased a new Ledger Stax and the Solana CLI does not support it. When trying to execute solana-keygen pubkey usb://ledger, I am getting an error saying "Error: no device found". It seems that only Nano S and Nano X are supported by the Solana CLI at this time.
When will add stax support to solana cli?
Thx

Please submit this as an issue to the GitHub repo that maintains the Solana CLI at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues -- since this is a question and answer forum, you won't get too much here unfortunately! There's an open PR for Ledger Flex at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/2808 so it shouldn't be too tough to add the Stax in a separate PR
